# imageView doesn't change image when I uploaded new image from firebase storage

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4.2

I try to get an image from url, First time loaded correct image form url,
But when I uploaded a new image, imageView doesn't change.
And I got this error from console :

> [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301)
>   [C7.1:2][0x7fa944135a30] get output frames failed, state 8196

Then I uploaded a new image again, 
imageView display last downloaded image and it shows the same error again.
Where is the problem?

```
ref.child("/user").child(userID).child("UserImage").observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(data) in

    let value = data.value as? String ?? ""
    print("url:",value)
    if let url = URL(string: value) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data,responds,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else if let imageData = data{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }
        }).resume()

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the SDWEBImage pod

`pod "SDWebImage"`

then you could just pass in the url

`self.userImage.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)`

more info about the pod is here  https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDWebImage

Comment: I try to use this pod, but not fixed the issue.

Comment: It still display last downloaded image

Comment: I think the problem is SDWebImage and URLSession load image from cache by default. But how to let imageView just download image and apply, not load from cache first?